# Error message for matplotlib: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.colorbar'

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I get the following error when I try to `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

```
" import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.colorbar'"
```

Happens with a file holding just the one line of code, as well as in code which ran
yesterday.

I have tried an alternate import form: `import matplotlib.pypot as plt`.
Tried to think of ways to avoid trying to import colorbar, which I don't need

Comment: `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and later e.g. `plt.colorbar(....)`. You shouldn't import colorbar explicitly.

Comment: I don't import colorbar explicitly.my code is just one line -  the following:  import matplotlib.pypot as plt

Comment: Where are you running this?

Comment: MacBook Pro, Ventura.  same environment for over a year.

Comment: Perhaps you have a local file named `matplotlib.py`? Did you try reinstalling matplotlib?

Comment: MacBook Pro, Ventura.  same environment for over a year.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I have to straighten out my Venv environment and then reinstall appropriately.  Will report back.

Comment: Bingo!!  Found my local copy in my Venv, reinstalled matplotlib, and all is well.  Thank you John C!!